# MySQL stop search N rows after first matching row (not LIMIT)

Tags: mysql, performance, raspberry-pi

I am performing an SQL query in a 600k row table and want to pick out rows which match a certain criteria (WHERE clause). Since I know that only max 500 rows after the first match may match the same criteria I want to skip searching the hole table for performance reasons. Also, it is most likely to find the desired rows in the "most recent" rows (with the highest row #counter).

```
SELECT
  timestamp AS "time",
  TimeAxis,
  WeightAxis
FROM ArrayLog
WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(coffeeTimestamp) = $usedTimestamp
```

`ORDER BY counter LIMIT 500` does not improve the speed of the query, I guess because the found rows are almost always < 500? The query takes around 20 seconds on my Pi through Grafana.
Is there a way to do this neatly or is this done automatically by the query optimizer already and it is already "as good as it gets"?

Comment: *`WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(coffeeTimestamp) = $usedTimestamp`* is not SARGable (study). Use `WHERE coffeeTimestamp = CAST($usedTimestamp AS DATE)` or similar - i.e. use the column as-is, not as an argument of a function.

Comment: Thanks, using the column as-is and not as an argument of a function was a very good clue!

Comment: The title is misleading.  You are not stopping a "search", but rather a "fetch".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you don't really care about the size of the result set, because you expect a reasonably small size.  Rather, your concern is about the performance of the query.  In that case, you make the query SARGable and then add an index on the `coffeeTimestamp` column.

```sql
CREATE INDEX cIdx ON ArrayLog (coffeeTimestamp);
```

Then, use this query:

```
SELECT
    timestamp AS "time",
    TimeAxis,
    WeightAxis
FROM ArrayLog
WHERE coffeeTimestamp = FROM_UNIXTIME(?);
```

The assumes that the `?` parameter (perhaps contained in the `$usedTimestamp` variable) would be a timestamp in seconds since the epoch.

Comment: Oh wow, okay so for now the `WHERE coffeeTimestamp = FROM_UNIXTIME(?)` improved my query by the factor of around 4.  I will look into indexing as well. Does the index continue to update as new data gets injected into the table?

Comment: To your last question in the above comment, yes, as you do DML (insert/update/delete), MySQL will have to rebalance the index.  There is a penalty for this, but it's usually small, and it makes your reads faster such that the index is worth using.

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful. What king of penalty? Performance during DML?

Comment: When the data is added/changed/deleted, the index has to be updated, and there is a (small) penalty for this.

Comment: Ignore the penalty.